# remove characters of a char array

Tags: c, arrays

In the str char array below I would first like to locate the first math symbol I see, then I would like to count backwards and remove whatever is between the previous three "`_`" and remove the three "`_`". Can I please get some ideas on how to do this?

So this:

```
 xa_55_y_*_z_/_+_x_+
```

Should turn into:

```
 xa*_z_/_+_x_+
```

My problem is I don't know how to remove:

```
_55_y_
```

Here is the code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char str [] = "xa_55_y_*_z_/_+_x_+";
    int length = 0;
    int decrementor = 0;
    int underscore_counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    length = strlen (str);

    for(i  = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        decrementor = 0;
        underscore_counter = 0;
        if(str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-')
        {
            decrementor = i;
            while(underscore_counter != 3)
            {
                if(str[decrementor] == '_')
                {
                    underscore_counter++;
                    printf("underscore_counter is %d \n", underscore_counter);
                }
                decrementor--;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @dreamlax thank you.

Comment: `if(str[i] == '_')` How can that ever be true? That line of code is inside another `if` block which  gurantees that `str[i]` cannot be `'_'`.

Comment: @kaylum thank you. I fixed my mistake.

Comment: And then what happened? It's not enough just to show your code. You need to describe what it is doing incorrectly and explain what it is specifically that you don't know how to do.

Comment: @kaylum it goes into  `if(str[decrementor] == '_')` like expected when the appropriate conditions are met. I just don't know how to chop the `_55_y_` out of the array. That is the reason why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Then please make it clear that that is your specific question. Your question currently reads.."I would first like to locate the first math symbol I see, then I would like to count backwards and remove whatever is between the previous three _ and remove the three _." That describes the purpose of the entire program and not just the bit you need help with.

Comment: @kaylum Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcspn.html) to find the first operator, which simplifies the problem a little. Then it's just a matter of going backwards and counting the underscores, and then just a matter of outputting the appropriate substrings, e.g.:

```
int main()
{
    char str [] = "xa_55_y_*_z_/_+_x_+";
    size_t firstOp = strcspn(str, "*/+-");
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    size_t i = firstOp;
    int underscores = 0;

    // go backwards looking for the underscores (or the beginning of the
    // string, whichever occurs first)
    while (i > 0)
    {
        if (str[--i] == '_')
            underscores++;
        if (underscores == 3)
            break;
    }

    // output the first part of the string up to the third underscore
    // before the first operator
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
        putchar(str[j]);

    // output the rest of the string after and including the operator
    for (size_t j = firstOp; j < len; j++)
        putchar(str[j]);

    // and a linefeed character (optional)
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Sorry for the poorly named `i` and `j` variables, hopefully it makes sense.